# Android - Bluetooth socket close command executes before OutputStream is Flushed

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I have an application that communicates to a thermal printer via bluetooth and prints data.

I write to the outputStream, flush to ensure that every data gets written, and then close the socket. However, what actually happens is that the socket.close() command executes before everything is printed out, so what happens is that the print out gets cut.

This is my sequence in writing data (it's in a giant try-finally block):

```
//open socket here, assign outputStream, write data to be printed


//after all those mmOutStream.write() statements, these are on the finally statement
mmOutStream.flush();

mmOutStream.close();
socket.close();
```

As you can see, I call in flush to ensure that all data gets written, I close the stream, then close the socket.

However, what I think actually happens is that the socket.close() statement gets executed even before everything has been printed successfully.

So far, what I've done is to put a Thread.sleep() command before the close statements but that's not the solution I want.

Does any one know how to ensure that the OutputStream is actually flushed/empty before closing the socket? I've looked at the documentation for Bluetooth Socket and OutputStream and there does not seem to be a straightforward way of doing what I want.

Any ideas would help. Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue in my app, but only in one specific case: when a Nexus 4 sends data. The other way round works fine (i.e. Nexus 4 receiving data). If I use two Xperia devices (one as client and the other one as server) it works too. So I think that this is a bug of the new Android bluetooth stack introduced with 4.2 version (because both my Xperia runs a lower version). Is your Android device running a 4.2 (ore greater) ROM?

Comment: My Nexus 7 is running stock 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the socket's output stream flushes it and closes the socket. Closing the socket itself is redundant. In your actual code it should do nothing at all, so adding a sleep before it should just be a waste of time.

Do you have any actual *evidence* for your strange belief that your program doesn't execute sequentially as written.

I would try *removing* the socket close.

Comment: If I remove socket.close, the try-catch statement where the device connection is made (bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice) fails. Also, I did not say that the program does not execute sequentially as written, what I said was that socket.close() executes before flush() finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fixed since 4.2.3. Prior to that BluetoothOutputStream used the default implementation of flush() from OutputStream which does nothing.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.4.4_r2/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothOutputStream.java